# Localhost error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-server, windows-server-2022

I have a new install of Windows Server 2022 with PHP8.2 and all the correct SQL SRV drivers.
The PHP pages access data from a SQL Server database on another (remote) server via port `1433`

My PHP pages are working OK when called from an external source (from the web) but when I try to access the pages from a browser on the server (via localhost) I get the following:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => -2146893019 [code] => -2146893019 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => -2146893019 [code] => -2146893019 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection ) )

The fact that this works fine for outside access but not for localhost would lead me to think that the actual install of IIS and PHP is 'fine', in as much as all the drivers and the versions are working (it is connecting and retrieving data).

However, I must be missing some sort of certification on my new MS Server 2022 install or there must be a misconfiguration somewhere I am not aware of.

This is my first install of IIS on Windows Server 2022 and I am keen to find out where the certificate issue is without the usual Microsoft goose chase.

Does anyone have any indication what is causing this error?

Comment: Whoever 'fixed' my question, please keep your edits to yourself. when you change a reference to Microsoft Server 2022 to SQL Server 2022 you are not helping me or the community! I don't care how many point you have - keep your edits to yourself.

Comment: Well you should use the correct terminology either SQL Server 2022 or Windows Server 2022 - the MS is superfluous, and "MS Server 2022" is unclear what you are referring to.

Comment: And you can see the edit history, including who edited, by clicking the "edited x time ago" link. You can even rollback edits.

Comment: No problem. I edited the question to avoid any confusion. Honestly if some people spent the amount of time helping others as they do being pedantic and making crazy edits then more might be achieved.

Comment: People may not know the answer to your question, but they may be able to clarify your question to make it easier for others. I suggest being less critical of peoples desire to help might benefit you.

Comment: Le sigh... have you tried reading the friendly documentation, [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228), instead of attacking the people trying to help you?

Comment: `localhost` is never going to be a valid match for a SSL certificate. If you issued the SSL certificate in the name of the machine then just use that to connect, rather than `localhost`.

Comment: The domain being used has no SSL certificate. That is part of what I am not understanding. localhost has no certificate - I get that, but what certificate is being passed to IIS to satisfy the encryption option?

Comment: If not configured then SQL Server will have a self-signed cert under the machine name. Exactly why that's trusted by the other machines is unclear: are you using `TrustServerCertificate=yes`? I recommend you get a proper cert for SQL Server especially if you use it over the network.

Comment: It's not complaining about the SSL/TLS certificate used by IIS, it's complaining about the one used by SQL Server. When you install SQL Server a self-signed certificate is created and configured by default to use for encrypted connections. If the instance is named `MSSQLSERVER` then you can see the certificate and its properties via SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER > right-click Properties... > Certificate tab. You can also import and/or choose different certificates here, such as ones that are Organization or CA issued.

Comment: This error is mentioned in the official documentation. Perhaps the content of the document will help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/certificate-chain-not-trusted?tabs=ole-db-driver-19.